# BoringSSL nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames ... get output frames failed, state 8196 log confusion

Tags: ios, objective-c, ssl, boringssl

We currently have two use cases for our objective-c application that connects to a node.js server.  The first case is having our application hosted on a client server where we have our SSL cert directly in node.js.  The second is our cloud hosted solution where we route everything through an Azure Web Application Firewall which has the SSL cert instead of in node.

My question or confusion is, when we connect to the azure server, our tablet application logs all of these BoringSSL logs and TIC Read Status Logs:

```
[BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C12.1:2][0x101843dd0] get output frames failed, state 8196
TIC Read Status [12:0x0]: 1:57
TIC Read Status [12:0x0]: 1:57
```

However, when we connect to a client server who does not use the Azure service, we don't see any of these logs yet both are using SSL.

We haven't seen any issues with any of the requests failing, but we are wondering if it could be contributing to poor performance of the course of several hours of use.

Is there something in the objective-c code or config files on the tablet that is triggering these logs or is this something in the Web Application Firewall?

These logs occur so frequently that it makes it very difficult to track and debug logs related to actual issues.

Comment: did you ever figure out how to silence these logs ?

Comment: @ajonno please try this solution to silence these logs - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69785611/swift-boringssl-metrics-log-metric-block-invoke144-failed-to-log-metrics/71931400#71931400