# How to eliminate boringssl log warning?

Tags: xcode, api, boringssl

I built a currency converter app, which gets the live currency value through API and display it. Testing on a physical phone my app works fine & no crash.

But whenever I do API call I am getting warning in the simulator as below:

```
[boringssl] boringssl_metrics_log_metric_block_invoke(144) Failed to log metrics
```

Here how i used URLSession

```
func performRequest(finalUrl: String) {
    
    if let url = URL(string: finalUrl) {
        
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        
        let task = session.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in
            
            if error != nil {
                print("error in network session \(error!)")
                return
            }
            
            if let safeData = data { 
                
                parseJason(dataUrl: safeData)
                
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
    
}
```

I have tried changing some values but nothing works

- OS_ACTIVITY_MODE = default
- DEBUG_ACTIVITY_MODE -> Debug -> any iOS simulator SDK = default

here my doubts are:

1. How to eliminate this warning?
2. Can I just ignore this warning?
3. Will Apple accept my app with this warning?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  It's driving me batty, and I'm seeing no (applicable, to me) solutions anywhere)!

Comment: As leonardo mentioned below, run the simulator on actual device instead of the Xcode simulator so that you will not have issues. Problem might be that our simulators are not able to connect to internet

Comment: Hey @Habeeb - please try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69785611/swift-boringssl-metrics-log-metric-block-invoke144-failed-to-log-metrics/71931400#71931400

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, ran the simulator on my actual device instead of the Xcode simulator and had no issue. Problem might be that our simulators are not able to connect to internet, I will look for a solution to that and comment if I find one but on the meantime attempt to run it on your physical device.

Comment: You are right. when running app with physical device warning is not popping up in Xcode simulator. Thanks for the idea !!

Answer (score 0):

- How to eliminate this warning?

You can't.

- Can I just ignore this warning?

I don't know, can you? It depends on how your brain works. I can ignore it, and I do. It's unimportant. So there is certainly no *reason* not to ignore it.

- Will Apple accept my app with this warning?

Apple will not *reject* the app *because* of the warning. Whether they will accept the app is another matter. No one knows what they will do.