# Failed to log metrics

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, swiftui

There is no Buildtime or runtime error on my code. however, when I run the code it says succeeded and a black screen comes up.
I get the following on my console after successfully running the app.

`2022-03-09 20:52:47.780476+1100 Firebaseauth[13847:7411556] [boringssl] boringssl_metrics_log_metric_block_invoke(151) Failed to log metrics.`

Any idea what it could be??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to register for BoringSSL log debug updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44410572/failed-to-register-for-boringssl-log-debug-updates)

Comment: The answer in the above link teaches how to hide the comments in the console. I don't want to hide the comment. I have an empty black screen.

Comment: The black screen is possible unrelated. Please [edit] your question with a [example]. See also [ask].

Comment: This is a good question, and no one has answered it.  @koen is incorrect to point asker to reframing the question.   The question stands; who is man enough to provide an answer in 2022?

Answer (score 2):

I can't take credit for this but found a working answer from [Evgeny Karkan in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71931400/):

Open a terminal and execute this command:

```
xcrun simctl spawn booted log config --subsystem com.apple.network --category boringssl --mode "level:off"
```

After running the above in a terminal, my issue went away and I did not see it again! I am running Xcode 14.1